# How to use compute shaders on mobile unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compute-shader, unity3d-shaders

I have been studying compute shaders and tried to test it on mobile phone (android). But it is always throwing error.

```
Kernel 'CSMain' not found
UnityEngine.ComputeShader:FindKernel(String)
```

Compute shader has no code.

```
// Each #kernel tells which function to compile; you can have many kernels
#pragma kernel CSMain

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
}
```

Here is the compiled version:

```
**** Platform OpenGL ES 3:
Compiled code for kernel CSMain:
#version 310 es

layout(local_size_x = 8, local_size_y = 8, local_size_z = 1) in;
void main()
{
    return;
}




**** Platform OpenGL ES 2:
  no variants for this platform (no compute support, or no kernels)
```

In the editor it works fine, but on android it seems to not work at all. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Tested on BlueStacks 
Project was created with URP 
OpenGL 2.0 was removed

Comment: What is your android version? What is your device?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Bluestacks emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, compute shaders are not fully supported on all mobile devices and how it will work varies from phone to phone. Some android phones have partial support while others might have no support at all. I haven't tested on iPhones but phones like Samsung Galaxy S6 have partial support.

Comment: I have had a relevant question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/192206/opengl-compute-shader-vs-fragment-shader-device-support , do you think you could please elaborate on this? :)